# Depth-Limited Search Recursive Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, search, pseudocode, depth

I'm looking at a pseudocode implementation of Depth-Limited Search, and I'm having trouble understanding it.

The pseudocode is:

```
Function Recursive-DLS(node, problem, limit)
    cutoff-occurred? = false
    if Goal-Test(problem, State[node]) then return node
    else if Depth[node] = limit then return cutoff
    else for each successor in Expand(node, problem) do
            result = Recursive-DLS(successor, problem, limit-1) 
            if result = cutoff then cutoff-occurred? = true
            else if result != failure then return result        
    if cutoff-occurred? then return cutoff else return failure
```

Im mainly having trouble understanding the reason for recurring the algo with limit-1 for every successor.  Can someone run through this with me?  Some graphical explanation would be nice haha.

I'm going to look at other sources in the meantime.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: looks like the pseudo code might have an error.  i think the test ( else if Depth[node] = limit then return cutoff) should be ( else if  0 == limit then return cutoff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo-code appears to be wrong. (It's actually possible for the base case to never be encountered if the node depth/limit values skip eachother - being simultaneously increased and decreased in each recursive call.)

The recursive case was written with the `limit - 1` so a base case can be reached (instead of "limit", think "remaining").

However, the base case for the limit is `if Depth[node] = limit then return cutoff`. Following David Chan's suggestion it should be `if 0 = limit then return cutoff`, which would agree with the `limit - 1` in the recursive case.

Alternatively, just pass `limit` in the recursive case and leave the current base case alone.

Comment: Yep, I've got that part.  But I'm wondering what it does for the search.  I want to know what it does in the high-level, if tha t makes sense.  I took a look at the wiki pseudocode and it looks MUCH simpler... Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: It "limits the depth".